# Zapier: How to do an init pull then instant hook in the same zap

Tags: zapier

Good morning,

I would like to create a zapier for my application which first allows me to pull my contact base and then be able to use the instant module via webhook. But all in the same Zap with the pool at init. Is it possible ?
I can't figure out from the documentation if this is possible?

Thanks in advance

I noticed that we could perhaps do this via several zaps. Or to put a schedule module but not sure that this is well optimized..